# Mutt configuration having an username which is different from the mail

Tags: mutt

I would like to configure my mutt files properly so that i can loggin and view my email account where the email is different from the username.
I have this

```
username:abc123
email:myemail@domain.com
imap server:mail.domain.com
imap port:000
smtp server:mail.domain.com
smtp port:111
```

One of my muttrc files is like this:

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes
set imap_user = "abc123@mail.domain.com:000/"                       
set imap_pass = `getpassword email_id`                                
set smtp_url = "smtp://abc123@mail.domain.com:111/"       
set smtp_pass =`getpassword email_id`                                    
set from = "mymail@domain.com"                            
set realname = "real name"                                  
set folder = "imaps://mail.domain.com:000/"                     
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
```

I checked some of the configurations (imap and smtp) on thunderbird, but i can't loggin. Is my sintax incorrect?What should i do?

Thanks.